# Computer Crash with coloured bars on screen

Tags: windows, windows-10, hardware-failure

I am having a problem with my computer that while playing games with heavy rendering load (Fallout 4 / Anno 2205) my computer will crash and I will get thick horizontal/vertical bars filling my main screen (seemingly in one of the major colours on screen at the time), my second monitor is fine (connected to onboard graphics). Sound continues for a little while after the crash and then stops. After this happens i have to physically restart the PC with the reset switch.

My PC Specs:

- MSI Z77A-G45 motherboard
- Intel i5 3570K @ 3.40Ghz with cooler master Hyper 212 Evo fan
- 8GB RAM
- MSI R9 270X Gaming 2G graphics card
- Corsair CX600M power supply

This also happened on my previous graphics card (MSI HD7870), which I RMA'd and got this one back from them.

I have installed the newest drivers, I have used MSI afterburner to check GPU temperatures and manage my fan speeds (temps will peak at around 60C, mostly static at around 50 during gameplay).

I also lowered the clock speed and power limit which stopped the problem for about a week, but it's come back since. There are no minidumps (or MEMORY.DMP file) created leading me to assume there is no BSOD in the background, but I have no idea what the problem is.

This is what the screen(s) look like after it has happened:

Main Screen:
[image]

Second screen:
[image]

The temps were 56C on GPU and 46C on CPU.

Comment: Your AMD display drivers are current?

Comment: Yeah, I've updated them a few times since I started getting the issue, yesterday is the latest

Comment: I will be honest.  The fact lowering the clock speed of the GPU seemed to fix it, sounds like, the card itself is not stable.

Comment: I thought that too, but I wouldn't have expected it to happen almost identically on two consecutive cards (both with stock overclock). I am using f.lux and I'm starting to think it might be that, though i'll need to test it a little bit more first.

Comment: I was going to say they could have send you the "repaired" card back but I suppose that isn't possible.  How did you manage to get a better card  because of a RMA?  **Wait....a minute!**  Your second screen works when this failure happens?  Why are both displays not plugged into the same device?  If the only display that does this, is the one plugged into the dGPU, then a critical failure with the dGPU is most defiantly to blame.

Comment: Apparently they couldn't repair it as it was too damaged and there was no equivalent they sell anymore (~3 years old) so slight perks i guess? I think the GPU/Onboard split was a BIOS Setting to enable the onboard, it has caused a couple of problems before, but this still happens even disabled. So if it definitely is the GPU, do you have any suggestions on how to test it? This is the reason i sent the last one back, but MSI couldn't replicate my problem (they sent me this one because apparently it was only outputting in greyscale).

Comment: If you have another system with decent enough specifications, boot up the same type of game (OpenGL/DirectX), and see if it will happen.  If Windows is not crashing, and the display driver is not crashing, the it must be the hardware.  There was an insane amount of work with Windows 8, to catch issues with display drivers, and prevent the entire system crashing like it did with Windows 7 ( which had improvements also compared to Windows XP)

Comment: Hmm, I'll see what i can do, might not be able to test it tonight though.

Comment: The second part of that comment was about your current system not the test by the way.

Comment: Well, I managed to test the card in my brother's PC and it does the same thing (his rig is almost identical to mine except for his GPU). So it looks like you were probably right. If you post as an answer I'll accept it for you :). Only thing left though is I wonder if it is my PC breaking GPUs or it is simply back luck.

Comment: Nevertheless you say that temp of the GPU is about 60, I suspect that it is still overheating of the GPU during the heavy load (you don't measure it during the game).

Answer (score 0):

IS you computer configured to generate DMP files?  The requisites are listed in this wiki

We do need the actual log files (called a DMP files) as they contain the only record of the sequence of events leading up to the crash, what drivers were loaded, and what was responsible.

Please follow our instructions for finding and uploading the files we need to help you fix your computer. They can be found here
http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wiki/windows_other-system/blue-screen-of-death-bsod/1939df35-283f-4830-a4dd-e95ee5d8669d

Can we also get your event viewer logs
Please read [this wiki](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wiki/windows_other-system/event-viewer-what-is-going-on-in-your-computer/fdda2010-d4df-4fed-863b-89ce0142419d) to find out how to find and upload your event viewer logs